# Itunes Thumb Drive Eject

Tags: macbook-pro, itunes, eject

How do I properly "eject" a thumb drive? I just uploaded about 26 hours of shows off of 12 thumb drives onto iTunes. Went to FILE, add to library, then when done loading, go to CONTROLS and hit eject, then remove drive. EVERY time it says failed to eject properly and shows the date of show, etc. What am I doing wrong?

New Macbook running latest version of iTunes.

Comment: Why can't you eject using Finder?

Comment: I wish I knew! When I hit eject it does nothing like say ready to eject or remove drive, and when I just do, it says I didn't properly eject!

Comment: I believe iTunes eject just means that iTunes isn't using it anymore. If you want to eject a flash drive, use finder.

Comment: I'll try that. So drive is shown in finder?